# How convert 2d vector to 1d array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to be able to do this without using C++ smart pointers. I tried the following

```
double* VecToArr(std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec) {
    double* newarr=new double(vec.size());
    for (int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++) {
        std::copy(vec[i].begin(), vec[i].end(), newarr);
        newarr += vec[i].size();
    }
    std::cout<<"inside \n";
    for (int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++) {
        std::cout<<newarr[i]<<"\n";
    }
    return newarr;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<double> x{1,2};
    std::vector<double> y{3,4};
    std::vector<std::vector<double>>vec;
    vec.push_back(x);
    vec.push_back(y);
    double *arr=VecToArr(vec);
    std::cout<<"outside \n";
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        std::cout<<arr[i]<<"\n";
    }
}
```

But inside the `VecToArr`, the output is:

```
inside
4.54e-322 2.18e-317 4.34e-311 4.24e-314
```

not `1 2 3 4` like I expected

And outside it, I get the same garbage values. Why is this?

Also, since I used `new` to create `newarr` inside `VecToArr`, where how do I `delete` it? In `main.cpp`, after I print out the values, do I just do `delete arr[]`?

**EDIT**

When I change the function to:

```
double* VecToArr(std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec) {
    double* newarr=new double[vec.size()*vec[0].size()];
    for (int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++) {
        std::copy(vec[i].begin(), vec[i].end(), newarr);
        newarr += vec[i].size();
    }
    std::cout<<"inside \n";
    for (int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++) {
        std::cout<<newarr[i]<<"\n";
    }
    return newarr;
}
```

The output is now `3 4 (garbage) (garbage)` instead of `1 2 3 4`.

Comment: You've called `new`--don't forget to call `delete`! Your MVCE has a memory leak.

Comment: where do I call `delete`? Is that the reason I'm getting the garbage output values?

Comment: `vec.size()` is just the size of one axis. `new double(vec.size());` make an array that is far too small.

Comment: You're getting "garbage output values" because right after you finish writing some values to wherever `newarr` is pointing, you immediately point it to something else with `newarr += vec[i].size();` *and then* try to output values.

Comment: `newarr` is both iterating over the length of the array (`newarr += vec[i].size();`) and is also intended to point to the first element of your array (you return it and print `newarr[i]`). It can't be both at the same time.

Comment: I made changes to the function as seen in the `EDIT`, but I'm still getting wrong values

Comment: You're still returning `newarr` after it has been modified (also that code is just invalid anyways as `i` isn't defined before the first line, but I'll assume that is a typo or something). See my answer as it addresses all of the concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three main problems are as others have mentioned in the comments and a bit more. Firstly, you're using the wrong type of new expression, `new double(...)` simply allocates memory for a single double and initializes it with the value of what was provided. You probably want `new double[...]` to allocate an array of the doubles.

Secondly, the size provided to this new is incorrect, only representing the first dimension of the vector (when it needs to be a sum of all the nested vectors' sizes).

Finally, you're returning `newarr`, which has been modified by the for loop inside the function and ends up pointing to the memory after where the allocation took place, you'll likely want to make a temporary copy of it at the start and return that instead.

With all the changes the final correct function may look like this:

```cpp
double* VecToArr(std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec) {
    std::size_t totalsize = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++) {
        totalsize += vec[i].size();
    }

    double* newarr=new double[totalsize];
    double* walkarr=newarr;

    for (int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++) {
        std::copy(vec[i].begin(), vec[i].end(), walkarr);
        walkarr += vec[i].size();
    }

    return newarr;
}
```

I'd also recommend passing the vector in by constant reference as currently it is being passed by value for (currently) no reason which may result in unnecessary overhead. Additionally, you should try to always use something like `std::vector` (or at least smart pointers) for allocation of memory rather than using `new`/`delete` directly (unless dealing with low level container implementation) as there is usually not much reason to at the expense of opening the program up to memory leaks.

Comment: what do you mean "it ends up pointing to the memory after where the allocation took place"? You mean when I returned `newarr`, it was pointing to `newarr[4]` instead of `newarr[0]`? That's why `walkarr` is needed?

Comment: @user5739619 `operator+=` will modify the variable in question, so as the iteration takes place it will add to that pointer (since it is to be used as the begin pointer for the copy), eventually ending up pointing indeed at `newarr[4]` in this case due to being added to twice. Since that is one past the end element of the allocated memory it is definitely not what you'd want to return and treat as the beginning of the array in your for loops which print out the values and assume it's pointing at `newarr[0]`. The copy is simply from when it was pointing at  `newarr[0]` right after allocation.

Comment: then why is it in the `EDIT`, the output was `3 4 garbage garbage` instead of `garbage garbage garbage garbage` if at the end, `newarr` points to `newarr[4]`?

Comment: @user5739619 It's undefined behavior, nothing about it needs to make sense at that point. For example when I compile your edit I get `inside 0 garbage outside 0 garbage garbage garbage`. If you ran a memory checker on it too you'd find it is doing out of bounds reads which could crash the program in practice, it just so happens that the memory allocated is probably next to some other memory in your program and it outputs that instead, but again anything could happen really.

Answer (score 1):

There are issues with memory allocation, indexing and pointer arithmetic. I have pointed out those in your code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

double* VecToArr(const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& vec) {
    double* newarr=new double[vec.size() * vec[0].size()]; // <-- you have 4 elements (also notice square brackets)
    double* newarr_ptr_copy = newarr;
    for (int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++) {
        std::copy(vec[i].begin(), vec[i].end(), newarr_ptr_copy);
        newarr_ptr_copy += vec[i].size(); // don't lose track of newarr
    }

    std::cout<<"inside \n";
    for (int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++) {
        std::cout<<newarr[i]<<"\n";
    }
    return newarr;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<double> x{1,2};
    std::vector<double> y{3,4};
    std::vector<std::vector<double>>vec;
    vec.push_back(x);
    vec.push_back(y);
    double *arr=VecToArr(vec);
    std::cout<<"outside \n";
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        std::cout<<arr[i]<<"\n";
    }
    delete [] arr; // make sure that you release the memory that you allocated
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this piece of code:

```
double* newarr=new double[vec.size()];
for (int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++) {
    std::copy(vec[i].begin(), vec[i].end(), newarr);
    newarr += vec[i].size();
}
```

A simple math fells violated here. You allocate your `newarr` to be the size of `vec`. So far so good. Now, for each element in `vec` you increment the pointer by `vec[i].size` - effectively leading to the used size of `SUM(vec[i].size())`. This is not right, you have undefined behavior in your program by accessing array outside of it's allocated bounds.

Please note, I also fixed a typo in your code - your original version of `new double(vec.size())` allocated a single double, not an array of them.